# External Linkage in c++

Tags: c++, linkage

I'm making a simple program dealing with poker hands and probabilities. I'm running test cases on various hands, and in my program I need a deck from which to draw my hand that is constant and global. My program has three main objects: Card, Hand, and Deck. I am trying to create a global deck but it seems no matter what I do I get an error saying globalDeck is undefined in hand.cpp. Here is the relevant code:

hand.cpp:

```
Hand::Hand(int &one, int &two, int &three, int &four, int &five)
{
    cardsinHand.push_back(globalDeck.copy(one));
    cardsinHand.push_back(globalDeck.copy(two));
    cardsinHand.push_back(globalDeck.copy(three));
    cardsinHand.push_back(globalDeck.copy(four));
    cardsinHand.push_back(globalDeck.copy(five));
}
```

and my cardgames.cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include "hand.h"
using namespace std;

Deck globalDeck;

void printresults(long successes, long trials)
......
```

Note: I have tried replacing Deck globalDeck with extern Deck globalDeck, extern const globalDeck, etc etc. Nothing seems to make it so that globalDeck is defined in hand.cpp. Also, the deck will stay constant throughout the program, so it could be declared as a global constant, or a global variable, whichever is easier. My error output is:

```
1>c:\users\\desktop\semesters past\winter 2013\computer programming\projects\cardgames\cardgames\hand.cpp(31): error C2065: 'globalDeck' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\\desktop\semesters past\winter 2013\computer programming\projects\cardgames\cardgames\hand.cpp(31): error C2228: left of '.copy' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'unknown-type'
```

Comment: Instead of using a global variable, use a class which contains your game state and handles the activities of the game within its methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your global variable in one header file

```
extern Deck globalDeck;
```

*and* define it in cardgames.cpp

```
Deck globalDeck;
```

Explanation:The compiler has to see what `globalDeck` is before you can use it. And the compiler mostly processes each *.cpp individually, without looking at others. In header files you can say what things are in the program without giving the complete and unique definition.

Comment: Added the "extern Deck globalDeck" to stdafx.h and it worked! Bonus points if you can explain to me why that's necessary, and what exactly header files and stdafx is all about (I'm a beginner).

Comment: The compiler has to see what `globalDeck` is before you can use it.  And the compiler mostly processes each *.cpp individually, without looking at others.  In header files you can say what things are in the program without giving the complete and unique definition.

Comment: @aschepler the explanation should directly be added to your answer. Upvote anyway

Answer (score 1):

The global variable `globalDeck` needs to be *declared* in every compilation unit (.cpp file) that uses it.  It needs to be *defined* in exactly one compilation unit.

A declaration of the form

```
Deck globalDeck;
```

is both a declaration *and* a definition.  A declaration with `extern` like:

```
extern Deck globalDeck;
```

is *just* a declaration and *not* a definition.

Header files (.h files) are just text that is included in other files with `#include`.  So you can put the declaration `extern Decl globalDeck;` in a header file (any header file) and `#include` that header file in every .cpp file.  You will also need the definition in exactly one .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

`class Deck` has not been defined in `hand.cpp` because a header is missing. You need to add something like `#include "hand.h"` or `#include "deck.h"`.

Comment: The necessary includes are there; this is just a bit of the code, not the whole file.